# C++ - Apply std::exp to an std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, std, exp

Is there a faster (from a performance perspective) way than simply do

```
std::vector<double> y;
y.reserve(x.size());
for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
    y.push_back(std::exp(x[i]));
```

Comment: This seems to me like an operation that can be done very efficiently using a GPGPU instead of a CPU. You cannot write compute kernels in standard C++ though.

Answer (score 0):

If you require maximum precision to the nearest ULP, this is likely as fast as you're going to get.

If you can accept some approximation errors, there are [much faster methods that use SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025373/fastest-implementation-of-exponential-function-using-sse).

Comment: Should be noted that the linked solution specifically applies to `float` calculations, not `double`.  SIMD does not necessarily have to sacrifice accuracy either, as `_exp` instructions exist for packed double.  So, if the compiler isn't automatically vectorizing this, then some speedup can still be achieved by hand-rolling SIMD calculations for a target architecture or using a vector library.

Answer (score 0):

`push_back`, surprisingly, has a little bit of overhead, because it doesn't actually know that you've reserved enough space, so it always has to check.  Because this check can change control flow between loop iterations, `push_back` precludes automatic vectorization by the compiler.

Consider these two functions, where the first one uses `push_back`, while the second one modifies a copy (or moved-into value) in-place:

```
auto exp1(std::vector<double> const& xs) -> std::vector<double> {
    auto ys = std::vector<double>{};
    ys.reserve(xs.size());
    for(auto x : xs){ ys.push_back(std::exp(x)); }
}

auto exp2(std::vector<double> xs) -> std::vector<double> {
    for(auto & x : xs){ x = std::exp(x); }
    return xs;
}
```

[We'll look at the assembly output](https://godbolt.org/z/Gh_h_J), if compiled in GCC 9.1 with

```
gcc -std=c++17 -O3 -march=skylake-avx512
```

Here is `exp1`'s inner loop (embedded in quite a bit of additional code which will never be executed because you've already `reserve`d):

```
.L45:
        add     rbx, 8
        vmovsd  QWORD PTR [r14], xmm0
        add     r14, 8
        cmp     r12, rbx
        je      .L44
.L18:
        vmovsd  xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        call    exp
        vmovsd  QWORD PTR [rsp], xmm0
        cmp     rbp, r14
        jne     .L45
```

And here's `exp2`'s:

```
.L53:
        vmovsd  xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        add     rbx, 8
        call    exp
        vmovsd  QWORD PTR [rbx-8], xmm0
        cmp     rbp, rbx
        jne     .L53
```

In practice, they are basically the same, because `exp` is complicated and GCC doesn't know how to automatically vectorize it.  However, consider the case where something much simpler happens in the inner loop:

```
auto sq1(std::vector<double> const& xs) -> std::vector<double> {
    auto ys = std::vector<double>{};
    ys.reserve(xs.size());
    for(auto x : xs){ ys.push_back(x*x); }
}

auto sq2(std::vector<double> xs) -> std::vector<double> {
    for(auto & x : xs){ x *= x; }
    return xs;
}
```

Here's `sq1`'s inner loop:

```
.L89:
        vmovsd  QWORD PTR [rsi], xmm0
        add     rbx, 8
        add     rsi, 8
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+24], rsi
        cmp     rbp, rbx
        je      .L72
.L75:
        vmovsd  xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rsp+24]
        vmulsd  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        vmovsd  QWORD PTR [rsp+8], xmm0
        cmp     rsi, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
        jne     .L89
```

Here's `sq2`'s.  Note that it uses `vmulpd` and `ymm` registers, and that it jumps by 32 bytes at a time rather than 8 at a time.

```
.L11:
        vmovupd ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdx]
        add     rdx, 32
        vmulpd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm0
        vmovupd YMMWORD PTR [rdx-32], ymm0
        cmp     rdx, rcx
        jne     .L11
```

Of course, this inner-loop snippet is a little misleading: it hides an immense amount of code used to deal with the remainder of the `std::vector` if its size does not divide evenly by 4.  Still, my main point is that yes, you actually can do marginally better than `reserve` + `push_back` (this surprised me quite a bit when I first found out), and that it would be significantly better if we weren't dealing with `exp` in particular.