# Any LogSumExp for Python implemented by AVX?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, avx

My project are heavily using `logsumexp` in the algorithm. Currently I'm using this library https://github.com/rmcgibbo/logsumexp , which is implemented in SSE instruction set.

However, modern Intel CPU has much powerful AVX instruction sets. Hence, I would like to know if there's any faster `logsumexp` implementation by AVX or even CUDA for Python?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, there are a few SO Q&As with fast AVX implementations of log and exp, using C intrinsics.  [Fastest Implementation of Exponential Function Using AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48863719),  [Efficient implementation of log2(\_\_m256d) in AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45770089) (also discusses single-precision `float`), and  [Logarithm with SSE, or switch to FPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8907932).  You could replace some functions in `mathfun.h` from your library with AVX versions.

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks a lot!